# Importing DBpedia's class hierarchy

Tags: rdf, owl, dbpedia

I'm using the DBPedia infobox properties and infobox types to import data from DBPedia. However I'm still missing out on the relations between classes. How can I efficiently retrieve the type hierarchy in a relatively easy fashion?  I thought about mapping DBpedia types to Yago types and then retrieving the yago type hierarchy, using

- http://downloads.dbpedia.org/preview.php?file=3.9_sl_links_sl_yago_types.nt.bz2 and
- http://downloads.dbpedia.org/preview.php?file=3.9_sl_links_sl_yago_taxonomy.nt.bz2.

Is there an easier or more straightforward approach to resolving this?

Comment: Do you just want [the ontology](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39#h305-1)?  That contains `rdfs:subClassOf` relations between the classes.

Comment: yep - do you have a recommendation on how to extract the data - specificially I only do care about the subClassof relation in Java / Scala?

Comment: If you're using Java, there are a few libraries available.  Jena and Sesame are commonly used.  You could run a SPARQL query asking for the the triples using `rdfs:subClass` (and you might ask for _all_ things that have `rdf:type rdfs:Class` while you're at it).  You could also get those results programatically through Jena's Model and the listStatements method, but the SPARQL query is probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either do this programmatically using one of the APIs for working with RDF, or you can do it using RDF querying tools such as SPARQL.  In both cases, you'll want to download the [DBpedia ontology](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads39#h305-1) (an OWL ontology serialized in RDF/XML).

### Using the Jena API to iterate through triples

Using [Jena](http://jena.apache.org/), you can load the data into a [Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html), and then use [listStatements](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#listStatements%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode%29) to select the statements that have `rdfs:subClassOf` as their predicate.  Note that `null` is used as a wildcard.

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;

public class IterateRDFSSubclassTriples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Model dbpedia = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        dbpedia.read( "/home/taylorj/Downloads/dbpedia_3.9.owl", "RDF/XML" );
        final StmtIterator stmts = dbpedia.listStatements(null, RDFS.subClassOf, (RDFNode) null);
        while ( stmts.hasNext() ) {
            final Statement stmt = stmts.next();
            System.out.println( stmt.getSubject() + " is a subclass of " + stmt.getObject() );
        }
    }
}
```

This produces output like this:

```
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/FilmFestival is a subclass of http://schema.org/Festival
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Embryology is a subclass of http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AnatomicalStructure
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Canal is a subclass of http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Stream
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Fern is a subclass of http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Plant
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Architect is a subclass of http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person
…
```

### Using SPARQL

You can run the following SPARQL query to extract all the subclasses and superclasses from `rdfs:subClassOf` triples:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?subclass ?superclass where {
  ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass
}
```

Using Jena's command line `sparql` tool, we find 541 such triples:

```
$ sparql --query query.rq --data dbpedia_3.9.owl | head
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| subclass                                                                   | superclass                                                     |
===============================================================================================================================================
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/FilmFestival>                                 | <http://schema.org/Festival>                                   |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Embryology>                                   | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AnatomicalStructure>              |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Canal>                                        | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Stream>                           |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Fern>                                         | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Plant>                            |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Architect>                                    | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>                           |
...
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/LegalCase>                                    | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Case>                             |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Lymph>                                        | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/AnatomicalStructure>              |
| <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City>                                         | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement>                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you want this data as graph, you can use a `construct` query instead, and you'll have a number of output formats available to you:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

construct where {
  ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass
}
```

```
$ sparql --query query.rq --data dbpedia_3.9.owl | head -20
@prefix :      <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:PoloLeague  rdfs:subClassOf  :SportsLeague .
:RacingDriver  rdfs:subClassOf  :Athlete .
:ResearchProject  rdfs:subClassOf  :Project .
# ...
```

```
$ sparql -out NT --query query.rq --data dbpedia_3.9.owl | head -20
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PoloLeague> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SportsLeague> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/RacingDriver> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ResearchProject> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Project> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Song> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/MusicalWork> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/NetballPlayer> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete> .
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Guitar> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Instrument> .
```

```xml
$ sparql -out RDF/XML --query query.rq --data dbpedia_3.9.owl | head -28
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SpeedwayTeam">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SportsTeam">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation">
            <rdfs:subClassOf>
              <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent">
                <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
              </rdf:Description>
            </rdfs:subClassOf>
          </rdf:Description>
        </rdfs:subClassOf>
      </rdf:Description>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/NoteworthyPartOfBuilding">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ArchitecturalStructure">
        <rdfs:subClassOf>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place">
            <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
          </rdf:Description>
  <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: How'd you do it porgrammatically? :P

Comment: @StefanKunze How exactly do you want the results?  Are you looking to get a model containing just those triples?  Or a way to iterate through them? Or something else…?

Comment: I'd like to iterate through that certain ontology file , so only processing subclasses relations.

Comment: @StefanKunze OK, that's not too hard using, e.g., Jena.  I have to run at the moment, but I should be able to post a code sample in a few hours.

Comment: @StefanKunze I've update my answer to show how you might do this programmatically using Jena.  There are lots of RDF APIs out there, and Jena is only one of them.  However, most will let you do something similar;  i.e.:  load the data into a model, select triples of a certain form from the model, do something with those triples.